How to disable warnings "Trailing closure in this context..."
The warnings sounds like: Trailing closure in this context is confusable with the body of the statement; pass as a parenthesized argument to silence this warning
before fix:
if let genres = item.genres?.compactMap { $0.genreName } {

after:
if let genres = item.genres?.compactMap({ $0.genreName }) {

How can I disable this warning or vice versa, make it mandatory?

Warnings are generally not configurable in Swift. If you're interested in elevating this to an error, see swiftlint which allows you to enforce stricter rules than the compiler.

Do not "disable" the warning: obey it! — You can elevate all warnings to the level of an error (making it "mandatory") very easily, but in my experience that is too broad a brush. As Rob Napier says, Swift Lint can help.

I tend to agree with the others: The syntax that the compiler is warning you about is very confusing. It's much better to use a form of this method that lets the reader tell the part that is a parameter to the function and what part is the the code to be executed if the if statement evaluates as true.
